# Enable blocked rows after in app purchase. Coding issue

Tags: swift, function, uitableview, swift2, in-app-purchase

I have an app that blocks User access to a few rows of a view controller. This is done by checking if a variable of type bool is set to true or false.

```
var unlocked: bool = false

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell!

    //blocking cells if they are not paid for.
    if unlocked == false {

        if ( indexPath.row  >= 2 ) {
            cell.userInteractionEnabled = false
            cell.contentView.alpha = 0.5
        }
        else{
            cell.userInteractionEnabled = true
            cell.contentView.alpha = 1
        }
    }
    return cell  
}
```

This works perfectly. I then have an option for the user to purchase access to the remaining rows, and hence the remaining content of the app. Once the In-app-purchase has been purchased it will run the function "updateSections()". I know this function is called upon purchase as I have tested it.

I now want to allow the user access to the remaining rows in the table view from the "updatedSections()" function as they will have paid for it.

What i have tried is:

```
//function to unlock
func unlockSections() {

    //This is the code for what happens once the device has bought the IAP. going to have to save what happens here in using nsuserdefaults to make sure it will work when the app opens and closes.

    print("The IAP worked")
    let unlocked = true
    tableview.reloadData()
}
```

However this does not seem to work. I can't see where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that this line:

```
let unlocked = true
```

is defining a new constant called `unlocked` which only exists in the scope of your `unlockSections` method.  It is quite separate from the property called `unlocked` which is defined at the start of your class.  To update the property instead of creating the new constant, just drop the "let":

```
unlocked = true
```

or if you want to be crystal clear (or you want to have both, but use the property in a specific case), use "self." to emphasise that you are intending to use the property:

```
self.unlocked = true
```